# Jasper Report - multiple column headers and footers

Tags: jasper-reports

I am doing a Jasper report which will have multiple column header, details, summary, footer.

For example:

```
Report with class A
-------------------------
John
Kelvin
Mary
-------------------------
Total: 3


Report with class B
-------------------------
Mark
Rose
-------------------------
Total: 2
```

Can someone guide me some idea to do that?

Answer (score 0):

try to create group of class so according to the group it will separate those name and add variable to some that calculate the count.